# ASP.NET MVC AJAX model's virtual object is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and C# to insert an object (POCO model class) into a database. The request and response is processed by JQuery AJAX.

The response is a strongly typed partial view which displays the object data. The html from the partial view is then appended to the web page.

The object class (Project class) contains a virtual object (Status class) which has more properties that should also be returned.

The problem I am having is that the virtual object (Status) returns as null when processed by AJAX. However if I disable the AJAX, the postback displays the correct virtual object data.

Not sure if it will help much but here are parts of my code.

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult AddProject(UpdateProjectModel model)
    {
        System.Guid guid = System.Guid.NewGuid();

        var project = new Project
        {
            Guid = guid.ToString(),
            JobNumber = model.JobNumber,
            Title = model.Title,
            Client = model.Client,
            Details = model.Details,
            StatusID = model.StatusID,
            LastModified = DateTime.Now
        };

        _projectService.AddProject(project);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var newProject = _projectService.GetProjectByGuid(project.Guid);

            return PartialView("Project", newProject);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Project class

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public string Guid { get; set; }

    public string JobNumber { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Client { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public int StatusID { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

Status class

```
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int StatusID { get; set; }

    public string StatusText { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is how to I get the Project Status to not return null when processed by AJAX?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the Status Property on your Project class? Something like:

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var newProject = new Project { Status = new Status { StatusText = "Testing" } };

            return PartialView("Project", newProject);
        }

Just to make sure its not your _projectService.GetProjectByGuid(project.Guid);
 thats not setting it?

Comment: Just noticed I'd forgotten to 'include' the virtual Status in the GetProjectByGuid method! It works now.

Comment: Great, are you able to delete your own question? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd forgotten to 'include' the virtual Status in the GetProjectByGuid method. It works now.

Comment: Cool. You've resolved the problem. Please mark this as the "answer", so that this question no longer shows up on the unanswered lists. :)